# keyUp/keyDown problems in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, keydown

I'm programming an app that will be a basic video game, but the keyUp:(NSEvent *) and keyDown:(NSEvent*) methods are failing to execute.

This is my code:

```
-(void)keyUp:(NSEvent*)event {
    NSLog(@"Key %@", event);
}

-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent*)event {   
    switch( [event keyCode] ) {
        case 126:
        case 125:
        case 124: 
        case 123:       
   NSLog(@"Arrow key pressed!");
   break;
        default:
   NSLog(@"Key %@", event);
   break;
    }
}
```

I made sure it was in a subclass of NSResponder (although it is in NSOpenGLView, could that be affecting it?) and other then that I don't see any problem. Any help is greatly appriciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you implement the NSResponder method acceptsFirstResponder to return YES?

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```